# SmtpFailedRecipientException not showing the complete message text

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, smtpclient

Sending mails via `(new SmtpClient()).Send(msg)` get me a `SmtpFailedRecipientException` with message "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay", not showing me the rest of the error text. I want to get the full error message text.

Comment: How do you know that there is other text now shown?

Comment: Thanks @Steve, I'm reading the message in my error logging system. I guess the server response was with the problematic email address.

Comment: Well, probably the remainder of the message is in the InnerException property. Something like: `if(smtpEx.InnerException!=null) Console.WriteLine(smtpEx.InnerException.Message);` Let me know if this is the case so I could change this comment in an answer

Comment: @Steve, I ask you some of time to change the logging system and tell the client to test the changes. Thank you!

Comment: @Steve are right, the `InnerException` have the complete error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete messages received by the SMTP stack could be found looking to the `InnerException.Message` property.

Something like

```
  if(smtpEx.InnerException != null)
  {
      LogMessage(smtpEx.InnerException.Message;
  }
```

also InnerException is an Exception and thus is present a InnerException.InnerException property with its message. And this goes on until a InnerException is null.

Comment: or `LogMessage(smtpEx.GetBaseException())`